# SQLite3 in C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, wrapper

I'm trying to use SQLite3 in C#.NET. I've googled around and found some different API's. I also checked SQLite's website for wrappers. I like them, but want to write my own wrapper without using an added dependency. All wrappers I find that don't require an added dependency aren't free.

**I'm wondering how one would read from, execute, and write to a sqlite3 database. Is it a socket connection(tcp? udp? etc?)?** I've tried searching this answer on google and all I get are library-specific answers. :/ SQLite's website docs aren't much help either.

**EDIT:** I also found a [COM interface](http://blog.gobansaor.com/2007/06/01/dhsqlite-new-sqlite-com-wrapper/) while googling, but is that library specific?

Thanks SO! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you looked at the [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/) library? It's a free ADO.NET library to interact with SQLite and requires nothing else in order to run, since it has the engine built into it.

I've been using it for a while now and find it really easy to work with. It even has a plugin for Visual Studio should you decide to use some strongly-typed tables with it or want to use it to add/create tables.

Comment: hmmm. I remember taking a look at that at one point. I'll re-investigate it now.

Comment: Thanks. I think you helped me clarify what I really wanted. I'll go try google with this clarification. :)

Answer (score 5):

(Answering the "socket connection" question.)

Part of the point of SQLite is that it's an embedded database - there's no server to talk to, you load the library directly into your process and it talks to the file system directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use SQLite in .NET, you should take a look at [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/), which is a ADO.NET provider for SQLite

Answer (score 1):

System.Data.SQLite is comparatively slower than other providers like SqlClient. I have look into its code.

Now I want to call it throw P/Invoke but not like SQLite provider. It call through P/Invoke every time when ever you access column value through DataReader