# How to port database from SQL Server Express to sqlLite

Tags: sqlite, sql-server-express, porting

I would like to recreate all the tables automatically. I have downloaded and installed Sqlite in Visual Studio and created an empty sqlite database. This should be the target. But which options do I have to import my data from a SQL Server Express database? Many Thanks

Comment: I have the feeling that it cannot be done automatically. I have tried some scritping tool in sqlserver but hw can i then convert to sqllite.

Comment: I would create a conversion program. Open the old DB and open the sqlite DB. Recreate the table structure, read the old table data and insert it into the new table. Repeat for all tables. Stored procedures ... i guess you Need to write them yourself in your target language.

Comment: Hi, thx I have done that manually as the db had few tables. Where can I get sqlite implementation for VS, so that i can use its namespaces. I mean write something like Using sqlite in my VS code

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/download.html and https://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html

Comment: I have downloaded the system.data.sqlite.core.1.0.108.nupkg file, that is what I need but I cannot know how to make visualstudio incorporate it.

Comment: Just add the amalgation sqlite3.c file to your Project and the Header files. Then you have it.

Comment: schorsch I am working with c#. And what will happen when I wanto to compile for another platform? I would better have a way to install the nuget package

Comment: I have found this file but I dont know how to use it in VS: system.data.sqlite.core.1.0.108 NUGet package

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145190/sqlite3-in-c-net answers your question about sqlite + C#